# Kotlinx Serializer and single-value domain types

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I love to use single-value types for e.g. IDs. How can I tell Kotlinx Serializer to consider such types as regular fields, not objects?

Example:

```kotlin
data class User(
    val id: UserId,
    val name: String,
)
```

should be serialized to:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: "foo"
}
```

and UserId is just `data class(val value: Int)`?

EDIT: I guess I *could* use custom serializer for each `Id` class, but I really don't wanna repeat such code for each and every ID in my domain. Moreover, I am not sure how to write one; so far my effort is failing.

EDIT2: this is my attempt for writing such serializer:

```kotlin
open class DoctorIdSerializer : KSerializer<DoctorId> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveDescriptor("id", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: DoctorId) {
        encoder.encodeInt(value.value)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): DoctorId {
        return DoctorId(decoder.decodeInt())
    }
}
```

basically, whats written [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md#representing-classes-as-a-single-value) but its not working :(

Comment: Have you tried making `UserId` an [inline class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html)?

Comment: You can consider using https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#json-path-query-api

Comment: @gidds yes, but inline classes are not supported yet by serializer